# Accessing query value after UNION statement

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm grabbing two sets of data from my database, and I need to merge them with a union, but I'm not sure how to access the second set of returned values with PHP. Any help would be appreciated! Some sample code:

```
$cracked=mysql_query("SELECT `49`.`Counter` FROM `all_user_data`.`49` 
UNION SELECT `50`.`Counter` FROM `all_user_data`.`50` ");

$result = mysql_fetch_array($cracked);
$thing=($result[0]); //I want to grab $result[1];
echo $thing;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you are returned together.  You need to loop over the entire array.

```
$values = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cracked)) {
    $values[] = $row['Counter'];
}
```

---

By the way you should switch from `ext/mysql` to mysqli/PDO if you can.

Comment: That's just what I needed! Thank you very much. Just out of curiosity, would switching to mysqli be as simple as changing my syntax?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `UNION` in a query, regardless of the number of `SELECT` statements, it will only ever return 1 result set.  The purpose of `UNION` is to combine multiple results into a single result set.  If you want to grab them separately, you'll need to run 2 separate queries.

For more information on `UNION` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html.